# How to find fields containing the TAB character in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server, what is the best way to identify all rows in a table where a certain column contains the `TAB` character (`CHAR(9)`)

Is it as simple as

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Field1 LIKE '%' + CHAR(9) + '%'
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`RTRIM` CHAR columns. like this:

```
SELECT        *
FROM          MyTable 
WHERE        (RTRIM(Field1) LIKE '%' + CHAR(9) +  '%')
```

Comment: What does add RTRIM to this specific query? with or without does not seem to change much in my tests

Answer (score -3):

Previous query fails, with: "missing expression" message,
In Oracle, this is the correct syntax

```
select *
  from MyTable
 where Field1 '%' || CHR(9) || '%';
```

Other solution can be:

```
Select *
  from MyTable
  where instr(Field1, CHR(9)) <> 0;
```

Cheers!

Comment: This question only has SQL Server tags. Your answer is redundant.