# Clickhouse how to filter string by control characters

Tags: clickhouse

In Clickhouse, how do I filter strings by control characters e.g. tab `\t`, newline `\n`

SQL Server has [`CHAR` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378167/how-to-find-fields-containing-the-tab-character-in-sql-server) to express control chars. Separately, Hive has [`rlike`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681554/inserting-hive-table-content-with-special-characters-tab-space-and-new-line) for regex expressions that can match control chars. How do you do something similar in CH?

I do not know how to escape the tab character properly in the following commands. No matter the number of backslash 1, 2 or 4:

```
$ clickhouse-client --query="SELECT 'Hello\tworld'"
Hello\tworld

$ clickhouse-client --query="SELECT 'Hello\\tworld'"
Hello\tworld

$ clickhouse-client --query="SELECT 'Hello\\\\tworld'"
Hello\\tworld
```

Clickhouse version 21.3.11.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the output in TSV format, so \t converted twice \t -> 0x9 -> \t

```
clickhouse-client --query="SELECT 'Hello\tworld' col format PrettyCompact"
┌─col─────────┐
│ Hello world │
└─────────────┘
```

You can use \t \n \r and char(9), char(10), char(13)

```
clickhouse-client --query="SELECT 'Hello\tworld' like '%'||char(9)||'%' res format PrettyCompact"
┌─res─┐
│   1 │
└─────┘

clickhouse-client --query="SELECT 'Hello\tworld' like '%\t%' res format PrettyCompact"
┌─res─┐
│   1 │
└─────┘
```